# Проблемы с Json, wordpress

Tags: wordpress, json, wordpress-плагины, alert

После того как я редактировал код плагина а именно удалил кнопку всего лишь которая особого функционала имела при переходе в редактор Елементор выводит сообщение: "Ошибка обновления: ответ не является допустимой ответом json" но при этом функционал никак обмежуеця и никаких проблем нет кроме как самого сообщения,  как это исправить и стоит если оно ни на что не влияет и может влиять?  заранее благодарю

Comment: А принципы SOLID вам ни очем не говорят?

Answer (score 1):

Я попробую ответить вам хотя сюдя по вопросу этого не возможно однозначно ответить без кода и всего остального.

Посмотрите в сторону SOLID. А конкретно на O которая гласит, что в объекты открыты для дополнения но закрыты для изменения. И в чем суть в том что изменяя небольшой функционал как вам кажется вы не учитываете того что это возможно где-то используется в следствии чего и появляется этот принцип. Думаю простое удаление кнопки это изменение класса и не в коем случае не добавление.